# Dismissing keyboard when user touches view

Tags: uiview, keyboard, touch, dismiss, first-responder

How can one dismiss the numeric keyboard when a user touches outside it?  I have found a good bit of documentation online but it seems to be outdated and isn't very clear on where any of this code goes.  I have tried using:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
        [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Where myTextField is my UITextField.  I tried placing it outside of but immediately following viewDidLoad in my main delegate file. I notice when typing it out that myTextField isn't autocompleting so I know that something is wrong. A programatic solution would be best.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try exiting edit mode

[self.view endEditing:YES];

Have you set all of your delegates?